# Java sockets in threads - no data transfer

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

I'm trying to create data transfer between server and client. Connection is established, but there is no transfer of data between server and client.
Server side:

```
    public static void CreateServerSocket() {
    try {
        server = new ServerSocket(9999);
        t = new Thread(new SocketServer());
        t.start();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(SocketServer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

}

public static void closeServer() {
    try {
        server.close();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(SocketServer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}

public static void sentSide(String side) {
    out.print(side);
}

@Override
public void run() {

    try {
        client = server.accept();
        out = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(), true);
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
        out.print("test from server");
        while (true){
            strIn=in.readLine();
            System.out.println(strIn);
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(SocketServer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Client side:

```
public class SocketClient implements Runnable {

static Socket client;
static Thread t;
static PrintWriter out;
static BufferedReader in;
static String strIn;

public static boolean CreateClientSocket(InetAddress ip) {
    try {
        client = new Socket(ip, 9999);
        t = new Thread(new SocketClient());
        t.start();
        return true;
    } catch (UnknownHostException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(SocketServer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        return false;
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(SocketServer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        return false;
    }
}

public static void closeClient() {
    try {
        client.close();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(SocketServer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}

@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        out = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(), true);
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
        out.print("test from client");
        while (true) {
            strIn = in.readLine();
            System.out.println(strIn);
            DialogMultiplayerStart.setSide(strIn);
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(SocketClient.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

The problem is that out.print is not sending data. Connection is established, because CreateClientSocket returns true, but neither out.print("test from client/server") is working, nor setSide method. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: have you tried doing `out.flush()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The client starts by doing

```
out.print("test from client");
```

and then waits for a whole line from the server:

```
strIn = in.readLine();
```

The server starts by doing

```
out.print("test from server");
```

and then waits for a whole line from the client:

```
strIn = in.readLine();
```

So, both sides are waiting for the other side to send an end of line: deadlock.

Change it to

```
out.println("test from server");
```

and

```
out.println("test from client");
```

to go a bit further. But you'll then have another problem: both sides read in an infinite loop, and don't send anything more.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I've changed `print` to `println` everywhere and changed while condition to `while ((strIn=in.readLine())!=null)`. But the problem is that method sentSide is still useless.

Comment: Read the end of my answer again: both sides try to read lines coming from the other side. But none of the sides writes anything. You should have a conversation: server writes, and client reads. Then client writes, and server reads, etc. If both read at the same time, nothing happens, and everything is blocked.

Comment: So, the change of the while condition is no help?

Comment: No. Instead of looping ad infinitum, you loop until the other side closes the socket. But since no one closes the socket, it's still a deadlock. Remember: you need a conversation protocol: the client sends 1 line, the server reads one line. Then the server sends 5 lines, and the client reads 5 lines. Then the client sends 2 lines, and the server reads 2 lines, etc.